# in Vxworks, under what circumstances Send() api will get stuck or take more time?

Tags: networking, vxworks

i am using two m/c A and B, both are having same vxworks image as well as hardware. but only change is application. suppose M/c A is server and M/c B is client. while communication over ethernet client M/c is not able send the data. it's getting stuck send() and task state will be Pend.

```
wState = send(vstCCEUSerSocket.wCCEUAcceptFD,(char* )vstCCEUAppTask.rgubyCCEUTxPkt,sizeof(vstCCEUAppTask.rgubyCCEUTxPkt),0);
/*logMsg("\nTrmtd = %d\t",wState);*/ 
if(wState == ERROR) 
{ 
   perror("write"); 
   Close the Fd
}
```

Comment: Can you post any code? Is the send() stuck forever or will it timeout?

Comment: it will send data after few minutes, and task will become ready. my communication frequency is 100ms.                             wState = send(vstCCEUSerSocket.wCCEUAcceptFD,(char*)vstCCEUAppTask.rgubyCCEUTxPkt,sizeof(vstCCEUAppTask.rgubyCCEUTxPkt),0);

  /*logMsg("\nTrmtd = %d\t",wState);*/

   }


 if(wState  == ERROR)
 {
  perror("write");
    Close the Fd  }

Comment: Seems you are running into the default TCP timeout which may be 5 minutes (according to http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5482). Send() is blocking. I know in VxWorks the timeout can be set to another value, but I need to check some old docs how it was done. Anyway you can look for an socket instruction to check if you are connected just before you send.

Comment: thnx for information. i am sure that i am connecting these two m/c before send()

Comment: How do you connect? Can post more code?

Comment: Not the Send call itself, but the underlying socket may be blocking. I see that I did not write that well in my other comment

Comment: here is the COnnect Code                                          if ((vwConnectionReturnVal = connect (vwsFdBDEUCCEUConn, (struct sockaddr *) &stServerAddr, wSockAddrSize)) == ERROR)                {
     logMsg ("Connection failed.Reestablishing..\n");
       close (vwsFdBDEUCCEUConn);
 taskDelay(1);
     }                          else
{
connection establised      }

Comment: The code without knowing all parameters that you have does not say much.

On the server side, do you socket() bind() listen() accept() ? before reading and writing ? If you do not accept(), you can't send data

Comment: under what condition socket will block????

Comment: by default a socket is blocking, unless you set it non-blocking using     on = TRUE; status = ioctl (sFd, FIONBIO, &on);

Comment: very late into the game, but I've seen issues with high communication frequeny connections "blocking" basically due to the reception side not being able to cope with them. That is actually the [TCP Zero Window](https://accedian.com/blog/tcp-receive-window-everything-need-know/) mechanism **working as intended**. Those cases can be generically analyzed via a Wireshark trace.

Answer (score 0):

From the [VxWorks OS Libraries API Reference](http://www.akae.cn/study/ebook/wrs/vx5.5/vxworks_os_libraries_api_reference_5.5.pdf)

Page 497/498 you can find info about the connect() but there's also a connectWithTimeout()

Page 1203/1204 you might find some interesting items for TCP sockets. For example the KEEP_ALIVE

If you rely on a quick connection time, and you want to keep control you can combine connectWithTimeout with the keep alive.

It can take another day for me to recall old code to check how I ever solved this in one of my projects.

[VxWorks 5.5 Network Programmers Guide - Stream Sockets](http://www-kryo.desy.de/documents/vxWorks/V5.5/vxworks/netguide/c-sockets.html#87079)

Comment: i dont have problem connection. Both m/c are getting connected properly only transfering data from client is the problem. my sending task getting stuck there.

Comment: Added another link to a stream socket client server application. These examples are simple and working. As I can't see your whole code, please take a look at the samples and compare to your code.

Comment: its same kind of code. i have created socket then trying to connect to server. if server accepts then only tranmitting the data to server

Comment: and does your server ACCEPT() an incoming connection as per documentation ? You don;t show detailed code so I can only guess what you are doing